# fullpage.js swipe on mobile scrolls through multiple sections

Tags: fullpage.js

On mobile when you swipe up slowly fullpage.js jumps ahead multiple sections like a fast forward or something ([my site](http://daveswebdesigns.com/) for example). Is there any way to turn off that feature? What I want is slow swipe up to reveal the lower section and animate to that section when you release. The demo on the main website [here](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage) has this behaviour, but I can't see any option for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure!
You can do that by using the [Drag And Move extension for fullpage.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/drag-and-move.html).

This will allow you to scroll like in [the demo page](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/).

Comment: Hi Alvaro, thanks for the fast response! Though I think you could mention somewhere that to get the plugin to work like the main demo it's actually £38 not 9 as one could assume.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'll take that into account! ;)